# How fast is an histogram suppose to decay?

Tags: audio, histogram

I am working on a software which receives streaming audio data, is expected to process that data on the fly, and then outputs the results.

The module I'm working on is expected to adjust the audio volumes if it gets too loud (to impose a limit of -17dB).

So far that works great, but the algorithm computes a loudness level using a histogram. That histogram has a +1 happen in one of it's 1,000 or so columns, but never a -1. I think that means it records the highest loudness and doesn't use an "instant" (within the last few milliseconds) loudness.

**My question here is: How fast is such an histogram expected to decrease?**

When I look at an audio software which shows the histogram graphically, I see a *slow* and smooth decay, but I'm thinking that may be to please the eye rather than a real loudness level.

Would it be better to keep track of the increase and then apply an opposite decrease after N ms? Or can I just do a decrement of all the columns once every 100ms?

I'd also be interested in a document explaining loudness if you know of such on the Internet.

##### *Notes for those interested by the code:*

My code is 100% based on the [Loudnorm module](http://k.ylo.ph/2016/04/04/loudnorm.html) found in ffmpeg.

The higher level source code is found on github in [af_loudnorm.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/af_loudnorm.c).

It also uses a lot of the code in the [ebur128.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/ebur128.c) file to compute the energy level and thus where to add 1 in the histogram.

Answer (score -1):

> My question here is: How fast is such an histogram expected to decrease?

> When I look at an audio software which shows the histogram graphically, I see a slow and smooth decay, but I'm thinking that may be to please the eye rather than a real loudness level.

Say "give the brain a chance to register what's going on" than "please the eye", and yes.  If the histogram moves too fast no one can make sense of it.

I sat in on a discussion a decade or more ago where I learned that pro audio DSP sound level meters all try to emulate the behavior of some one cannonical electro-mechanical VU meter from the mid 20'th century because that's what folks are used to.  This makes good sense if you want something that a sound engineer can interpret -- it may not be best if you want to do the most pleasing job of keeping sound leveled.

> Would it be better to keep track of the increase and then apply an opposite decrease after N ms? Or can I just do a decrement of all the columns once every 100ms?

Do you want to track the sound for visual purposes, or do you want to use the histogram to control sound levels?  If it's the latter -- you want to experiment and find out what sounds good, particularly after sudden peaks.  On the one hand, if the sound cuts out for a while after an explosion, that's bad.  On the other hand, if the soft passages in a symphony end up the same volume as the loud passages -- that's bad too.

You need to find a balance, and because it's **psycho**acoustics, there'll be some art involved.

I suggest doing a literature search on the Internet -- I'd start with the keywords "psychoacoustics" and "automatic volume control", but my Google Fu is notoriously bad.  (Put the "psychoacoustics" in there so you get serious engineering papers -- but try it without just in case).

Comment: I'm looking at the histogram to *perfectly* control sound levels! :-) My concern is that the level before the explosion and after the explosion is not going to be the same if I keep the explosion levels in the histogram. In other words, the same person talking before and after would be at a lower volume after the loud explosion... and that's a concern.